# Increase in http request 'Wait' time while mysql is performing many imports

Tags: mysql, linux, laravel, mariadb

Using Laravel, I have setup some cronjobs (through the scheduler) to run multiple instances of an import script that collects data from APIs into a MariaDB relational database. I have been running around 20 instances so that about 20 imports are done, simultaneously, each second.

While these are running, the web pages (http/s requests) are responding much slower. Testing with pingdom's website speed test, the difference is a long "Wait" time of 3000ms for the main page document. As soon as I stop the importing of data, the Wait time is only about 300ms.

Looking at server usage when the imports are running (compared to when they are not running) I'm not seeing any noticeable difference to CPU usage or memory usage. CPU is at about 3-30% regardless of the import scripts, and ram usage is only about 2GB higher (server typically uses 30GB/48GB of ram). Everything looks OK.

I'm considering what the bottlenecks could be considering the server usage has plenty of room to operate - perhaps it could be table locking?

What options do I have in order to allow these imports to continue without slowing the site down?

Running NGINX on Linux Ubuntu.

Comment: Bottleneck may be disk usage if you are strongly writing on disks.

Comment: Could you offer any ideas on how to test if disk usage is the bottleneck?

Comment: Details, please.  It sounds like you are scraping 20 web pages per second, but what happens then?  Parsing the pages?  Inserting one row?  Inserting a million rows per page?  How many CPUs?  Is the network bandwidth saturated?  Etc, etc.

Comment: 1. Opens text files and reads line-by-line, then using the word from each line, it proceeds with the next steps, 2. Grabs data from sources, passing the word from the text file, 3. Parses data to be stored, 4. Insert 1 row for main record, 5. Insert multiple other relational rows as needed (other tables). ~ Honestly I'm not sure how to check 'network bandwidth saturation'.